# Efficiency of Numpy wheels and simple benchmark for Numpy installations

Tags: python, numpy

Some months (or years?) ago, I installed a Numpy wheel which was very inefficient. Since, I avoid wheels for the computational packages and prefer to build them or to use conda.

By " very inefficient", I mean that a code using this wheel was something like 10 times slower than usual. I guess this Numpy did not manage to use correctly the Blas and/or Lapack implementations installed on the system (Debian).  See https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/building.html

Note that for Linux, the wheels are built on an old CentOS (https://github.com/pypa/manylinux).

But a generically compiled Numpy (a wheel) can also be less efficient than a Numpy compiled on the machine because it is not compiled with options like `march=native`, so I guess it uses only the most generic processor instructions.

This is why I think when we really care about performance, one needs to be able to check how fast is the installed Numpy.

Now I try to use [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) and [pipenv](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv), which seem very convenient but using pipenv without wheels would be very slow and inconvenient.

I'm wondering how efficient are the wheels of Numpy (and other computational packages).

Note that I found nothing about the efficiency of the wheels in the installation pages of Numpy and Scipy (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/install.html and https://scipy.org/install.html#installing-via-pip)

I'm also wondering how to bench the Numpy installations. I can benchmark with a very simple code like

```
import numpy as np
a = np.random.rand(1000)
%timeit a @ a
```

which already gives a good idea but it only benchmark one Numpy function.

I didn't find anything very simple. For example there is https://github.com/numpy/numpy/tree/master/benchmarks but one needs to download the Numpy source. I guess that there are commands using only the installed Numpy.

There are bench functions (for example `np.lib.bench()` or `np.random.bench()`) but the documentation is not so clear and I don't understand how to use them.

To summarize, my questions are (yes, 2 questions, but they are strongly related and I don't see why they should be split):

- When we care about performance, is it a good practice to rely on wheels (especially for Numpy)? Will it be slower than using (for example) a conda built Numpy?
- Are there simple commands to benchmark Numpy installations and get a good idea of their overall performance?

Comment: On Windows have a look at https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

Comment: What do you mean  by it "was very inefficient"?

Comment: What in particular is your question?

Comment: I edited the question to try to answer the comments.

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on exactly what kind of math you're doing.  Wheels on PyPI are built with OpenBLAS, whereas the default conda packages use MKL.  The performance between the two is reasonably competitive.  Intel has been doing more work lately on some low-level numpy stuff, and the conda packages will benefit from that, while the wheels currently will not.

We recently ran benchmarks that may be of interest to you: https://www.anaconda.com/blog/developer-blog/improved-security-performance-in-anaconda-distribution-5/